# What is the meaning and usage of “Turtles all the way down”

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms

Can someone please explain the meaning and usage of

> **"Turtles all the way down"**

in simple words? I read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down) and have some level of understanding of it but was hoping someone would make it more clear here. For instance, I would like to know if this expression is used on a day to day conversation? Is this expression understood by all native English speakers regardless of their specific knowledge of the background of the phrase?

Comment: This was also an EL&U question some while ago but the answers might be of interest: [Does “Turtles all the way down” mean endless continuation…](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128655/does-turtles-all-the-way-down-mean-endless-continuation-exercise-of-somethin) Another: [Why “it’s turtles” not “they are turtles”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73815/why-it-s-turtles-not-they-are-turtles)

Comment: I think you accepted the answer too soon. You want to know if this phrase is common in daily conversation and if native speakers are generally aware of its meaning. I *don't* know, so you need someone currently living in an anglophone country (who's also a bit of a nerd) to answer those specific requests.

Comment: It's not an idiom, but an allusion, and many people would not recognize the allusion.

Comment: There's an extensive [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down) on this expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase is usually used to describe any system that appears to have dependencies that never end.

Comment: Do native speakers understand its meaning? Could you use this expression in a shop, at work, at a dinner, etc. and be understood? Is it an idiom?  I think it's a geeky expression that your ordinary man on the street will be unfamiliar with, but that's just me guessing.

Comment: It is from a humorous story about the cosmology of the world. Many speakers would recognize the reference.